# How to decode the one hot encoder values in spark ml

Tags: logistic-regression, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

Is it possible to perform oneHotDecoder after using OneHotEncoder in spark ml? Is there any way to achieve this?

```
StringIndexer dateIndexer = new StringIndexer();
csvData = dateIndexer.setInputCol("Date").setOutputCol("dateIndex").fit(csvData).transform(csvData);
StringIndexer timeIndexer = new StringIndexer();
csvData = timeIndexer.setInputCol("Time").setOutputCol("timeIndex").fit(csvData).transform(csvData);
OneHotEncoderEstimator encoder = new OneHotEncoderEstimator(); csvData = encoder.setInputCols(new String[] { "dateIndex", "timeIndex"}).setOutputCols(new String[] { "dateVector", "timeVector"}).fit(csvData).transform(csvData);
```

I could not find any solution on this in the spark API docs.

Comment: Please provide a code sample of what you have attempted as a starting point for you to receive help

Comment: StringIndexer dateIndexer = new StringIndexer();
  csvData=dateIndexer.setInputCol("Date")
    .setOutputCol("dateIndex")
    .fit(csvData)
    .transform(csvData);
  
  StringIndexer timeIndexer = new StringIndexer();
  csvData=timeIndexer.setInputCol("Time")
  .setOutputCol("timeIndex")
  .fit(csvData)
  .transform(csvData);OneHotEncoderEstimator encoder = new OneHotEncoderEstimator();
  csvData = encoder.setInputCols(new String[] {"dateIndex","timeIndex"})
   .setOutputCols(new String[] {"dateVector","timeVector"})
   .fit(csvData).transform(csvData);